# Integral of $\arccos$ function combined with exponontial function

Tags: definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-integrals

Is it possible to calculate this integral?

$$\int_0^1 x^{j}\  e^{ax^2}\arccos(x)\ dx,\qquad a\in\mathbb{R}_+,\ j\in\mathbb{N}. $$

Although the integral looks neat and fairly simple in form. I tried evaluating it using integration by parts but without success. I also couldn't find the solution in the book, "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products" by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik and Prudnikov, Brychkov, - Integrals and Series 1-3.

Can anyone help me in solving this?

Thank you.

Comment: As the domain of integration is a bounded interval, I would recommend you to work with the taylor expansion of the gaussian and arccos factors. Or perhaps there exists a smart Feynman's trick for that case.

Comment: Odd j seem to be able to integrate into an expression with Bessel functions, while even j can be integrated into 2F2 hypergeometrics. I am unable to find the general case j though.

Comment: @CaptainChicky in this case j is odd, but i can't see how you get the Bessel functions?

Comment: After calculation, i found this result but i can't find the Bessel function 
$$
I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \frac{\Gamma(k+3 / 2)}{(k+1)^2 \Gamma(k+1)}{ }_2 F_2\left(k+1, k+3 / 2 ; k+2, k+2 ;-b^2\right)
$$
where $j=2k+1$ and $b=-a^2$.